# spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch gives results for @Query in 2.4.4 version & no results for the same query & data point in 2.5.13 version

Tags: spring-data-elasticsearch

I have my Query this way :-

```
@Repository
@Timed
public interface EmployeeRepository extends ElasticsearchRepository <Employee, String> {    
    @Query("{"terms":{"id": ?0}}")
    @Timed
    public Page<Employee> findByEmployeeIds(List<Long> ids);
}
```

I was earlier using spring-boot-starter-parent-2.4.4 which is using Spring-boot-starter-data-Elasticsearch 2.4.4 version

Internally this query is generating below query which hits ES Index and it is giving results

```
{"from":0,"size":50,"query":{"wrapper":
{"query":"eyJib29sIjogeyJtdXN0IjogW3sidGVybXMiOiB7ImlkIjogWyJcIjEyMyJcIiwiXCIyNDUiXCJdfX1dfX0="}},"version":true,"explain":false}
```

I saw in some forum that Base64 Encryption is used and I tried decoding the encrypted value inside my wrapper and this is the output of it :-

```
{"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"id": ["\"123"\","\"245"\"]}}]}}
```

When I upgrade starter parent to 2.5.13, it is referring to 2.5.13 version of elasticsearch data starter parent. And with 2.5.13 version same query and same data pointing to same index not giving results. I debugged to see the internal query generated

```
{"from":0,"size":50,"query":{"wrapper":
{"query":"eyJib29sIjogeyJtdXN0IjogW3sidGVybXMiOiB7ImlkIjogWyJcIjEyM1wiIiwiXCIyNDVcIiJdfX1dfX0="}},"version":true,"explain":false}
```

On decoding the wrapper this is the below query where the id values are not properly enclosed in double quotes

```
{"bool": {"must": [{"terms": {"id": ["\"123\"","\"245\""]}}]}}
```

I also noticed that @Query methods that is have List as paremeter in method arguments are causing the issue. As we are using terms query this would look for exact word and slash appended to it is not found in index which is giving no results.

Is this a bug or do I have to change anything from our end.

1. Changes wise we have lots of such queries and impact is more. Would require regression followed by changes and this is going to be really huge effort.
2. And we don't want to downgrade the version as we don't want to invite vulnerabilites coming from the lower versions.

Can someone please help or suggest me on this.

Answer (score 0):

The first query does not decode to a valid json, that's strange.

As for the versions: Spring Boot 2.4.x pulls in Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.1.x and Spring Boot 2.5.x pulls Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.2.x. Both of these versions of Spring Data Elasticsearch are out of maintenance already. The current version is Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4 (Boot 2.7), 4.3 (Boot 2.6) is also still maintained.

Using the current versions (Boot 2.7.0 with Spring Data Elasticsearch 4.4.0) and the following method:

```java
@Query("{\"terms\":{\"id\": ?0}}")
SearchHits<Foo> findByIdsWithTermsQuery(List<Long> ids);
```

calling the method with:

```java
repository.findByIdsWithTermsQuery(Arrays.asList(123L, 245L));
```

produces the following

```json
{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"wrapper":{"query":"eyJ0ZXJtcyI6eyJpZCI6IFsxMjMsMjQ1XX19"}},"version":true,"explain":false}
```

where the extracted wrapped query is

```json
{"terms":{"id": [123,245]}}
```

As you see, in the actual version the list of long values is correctly written and not wrapped in any quotes at all.

If I change the type of the parameter to Strings and the call as well:

```java
@Query("{\"terms\":{\"id\": ?0}}")
SearchHits<Foo> findByIdsWithTermsQuery(List<String> ids);

repository.findByIdsWithTermsQuery(Arrays.asList("123", "245"));
```

then the wrapped query changes to a list of strings as well:

```json
{"from":0,"size":10000,"query":{"wrapper":{"query":"eyJ0ZXJtcyI6eyJpZCI6IFsiMTIzIiwiMjQ1Il19fQ=="}},"version":true,"explain":false}

{"terms":{"id": ["123","245"]}}
```

There had been issues with parameter lists in `@Query` methods (and currently we have an open pull request to fix a related issue in the reactive code) so you should upgrade to the current version of Spring Data Elasticsearch as this handles this case correctly.

Comment: Thanks alot for your help. This would help me with minimal effort.
I tried using spring data elasticsearch 4.4.1 version and still facing same issue. Can you please confirm me if 4.4.1 is the version you were suggesting.

Comment: Well I tried with 4.4.0, as 4.4.1 was released just yesterday and will then be used by boot 2.7.1 I assume

Comment: How to decode the  query of `eyJ0ZXJtcyI6eyJpZCI6IFsxMjMsMjQ1XX19` ?

Comment: by using the base64 decoding tool of your choice (`echo "eyJ0ZXJtcyI6eyJpZCI6IFsxMjMsMjQ1XX19" | base64 -d` or dump it into https://www.base64decode.org/